# Why can't I return a ByteString from a Handler in Yesod?

Tags: haskell, yesod, bytestring

I'm trying to return a `ByteString` from my `Handler` function in Yesod:

```
getHomeR :: Handler ByteString
getHomeR = return "foo"
```

but I'm getting this error:

```
/Users/maximiliantagher/Documents/Mercury/hs/mercury-web-backend/src/Application.hs:48:1: error:
    • No instance for (ToTypedContent ByteString)
        arising from a use of ‘yesodRunner’
    • In the expression:
        yesodRunner getHomeR env1404_axwe (Just HomeR) req1404_axwf
      In a case alternative:
          "GET"
            -> yesodRunner getHomeR env1404_axwe (Just HomeR) req1404_axwf
      In the expression:
        case Network.Wai.Internal.requestMethod req1404_axwf of {
          "GET"
            -> yesodRunner getHomeR env1404_axwe (Just HomeR) req1404_axwf
          _ -> yesodRunner
                 (void badMethod) env1404_axwe (Just HomeR) req1404_axwf }
```

Why is this happening and why doesn't `ByteString` have a `ToTypedContent` instance?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `ToTypedContent` class describes what the `content-type` is of the data. So types that have an associated content type (e.g. UTF 8 for `Text` or `Value` (JSON)) can have a natural `ToTypedContent` instance.

The problem with `ByteString` is that it describes any binary data—your `ByteString` could be a PNG, a JPEG, or anything, so it's unclear what content type to give it.

If you really just want to return binary data, the `octet-stream` content type is appropriate:

```
getHomeR :: Handler TypedContent
getHomeR = return $ TypedContent typeOctet $ toContent ("x" :: ByteString)
```

But you should try for a better content type if possible (e.g. `image/jpeg` for JPEG).

In that case, you can either use the `TypedContent` manually as above, or write your own instance of `ToTypedContent` for a newtype over `ByteString`

```
newtype Jpeg = Jpeg ByteString deriving (Show, ToContent)

instance ToTypedContent Jpeg where
    toTypedContent h = TypedContent "image/jpeg" (toContent h)
```